# Using the same logic array_values() works outside project but not inside project

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace the numeric indexes in my multidimensional array, so indexes will start from 0 instead of 91.
I tried to run this code below outside of my project to make sure it works fine. And it does work.

```
$data_sent = array
        (
            "1" => array
                (
                    "id_paragraphe" => array
                        (
                            "91" => 1,
                            "92" => 4,
                            "93" => 9,
                            "94" => 2,
                            "95" => 7,
                            "96" => 10,
                            "97" => 3,
                            "98" => 8,
                            "99" => 11
                        ),

                    "texte_tableau_paragraphe" => array
                        (
                            "91" => 'colonne1 ligne1 hhhhh',
                            "92" => 'colonne2 ligne1 22222222222',
                            "93" => 'colonne3 ligne1 333333333333',
                            "94" => 'colonne1 ligne2 444444444',
                            "95" => 'colonne2 ligne2 5555555555555',
                            "96" => 'colonne3 ligne2 6666666666666',
                            "97" => 'colonne1 ligne3 777777777sdfgvsd',
                            "98" => 'colonne2 ligne3 88888888888',
                            "99" => 'colonne3 ligne3 9999999999999'
                        ),

                    "id_lettre" => array
                        (
                            "6" => 30744
                        )

                ),

            "2" => Array
                (
                    "id_paragraphe" => array
                        (
                            "0" => 16,
                            "1" => 17,
                            "2" => 18,
                            "3" => 19,
                            "4" => 20,
                            "5" => 21,
                            "6" => 22,
                            "7" => 23,
                            "8" => 24,
                            "9" => 25,
                            "10" => 26,
                            "11" => 27,
                            "12" => 28,
                            "13" => 29,
                            "14" => 30,
                            "15" => 31,
                            "16" => 32,
                            "17" => 33,
                            "18" => 34,
                            "19" => 35,
                            "20" => 36,
                            "21" => 37,
                            "22" => 38,
                            "23" => 39,
                            "24" => 40,
                            "25" => 41,
                            "26" => 42,
                            "27" => 43,
                            "28" => 44,
                            "29" => 45,
                            "30" => 46,
                            "31" => 47,
                            "32" => 48,
                            "33" => 49,
                            "34" => 50,
                            "35" => 51,
                            "36" => 52,
                            "37" => 53,
                            "38" => 54,
                            "39" => 55,
                            "40" => 56,
                            "41" => 57,
                            "42" => 58,
                            "43" => 59,
                            "44" => 60,
                            "45" => 61,
                            "46" => 62,
                            "47" => 63,
                            "48" => 64,
                            "49" => 65,
                            "50" => 66,
                            "51" => 67,
                            "52" => 68,
                            "53" => 69,
                            "54" => 70,
                            "55" => 71,
                            "56" => 72,
                            "57" => 73,
                            "58" => 74,
                            "59" => 75,
                            "60" => 76,
                            "61" => 77,
                            "62" => 78,
                            "63" => 79,
                            "64" => 80,
                            "65" => 81,
                            "66" => 82,
                            "67" => 83,
                            "68" => 84,
                            "69" => 85,
                            "70" => 86,
                            "71" => 87,
                            "72" => 88,
                            "73" => 89,
                            "74" => 90,
                            "75" => 91,
                            "76" => 92,
                            "77" => 93,
                            "78" => 94,
                            "79" => 95,
                            "80" => 96,
                            "81" => 97,
                            "82" => 98,
                            "83" => 99,
                            "84" => 100,
                            "85" => 101,
                            "86" => 102,
                            "87" => 103,
                            "88" => 104,
                            "89" => 105,
                            "90" => 106
                        ),

                    "texte_tableau_paragraphe" => array
                        (
                            "0" => "lorem ipsum1",
                            "1" => "lorem ipsum2",
                            "2" => "lorem ipsum3",
                            "3" => "lorem ipsum4",
                            "4" => "lorem ipsum1455",
                            "5" => "lorem ipsum177",
                            "6" => "lorem ipsum78",
                            "7" => "lorem ipsum41",
                            "8" => "100,000",
                            "9" => "400,000",
                            "10" => "100,000",
                            "11" => "100,000",
                            "12" => null,
                            "13" => "700,000",
                            "14" => "lorem ipsum1489",
                            "15" => "6.50%",
                            "16" => "6.50%",
                            "17" => "6.50%",
                            "18" => "6.50%",
                            "19" => null,
                            "20" => null,
                            "21" => "lorem ipsum178996",
                            "22" => null,
                            "23" => null,
                            "24" => null,
                            "25" => null,
                            "26" => null,
                            "27" => null,
                            "28" => "lorem ipsum199999",
                            "29" => "17.80822",
                            "30" => "71.23288",
                            "31" => "17.80822",
                            "32" => "17.80822",
                            "33" => "0.00000",
                            "34" => "124.65753",
                            "35" => "lorem ipsum188",
                            "36" => "0.017808%",
                            "37" => "0.017808%",
                            "38" => "0.017808%",
                            "39" => "0.017808%",
                            "40" => "0.000000%",
                            "41" => null,
                            "42" => "lorem ipsum1179365",
                            "43" => "7/25/2013",
                            "44" => "7/26/2013",
                            "45" => "7/1/2014",
                            "46" => "5/19/2014",
                            "47" => null,
                            "48" => null,
                            "49" => "lorem ipsum21",
                            "50" => "7/25/2013",
                            "51" => "7/26/2013",
                            "52" => "3/11/2014",
                            "53" => "5/19/2014",
                            "54" => null,
                            "55" => null,
                            "56" => "lorem ipsum278",
                            "57" => "3/31/2015",
                            "58" => "3/31/2015",
                            "59" => "3/31/2015",
                            "60" => "3/31/2015",
                            "61" => null,
                            "62" => null,
                            "63" => "lorem ipsum277",
                            "64" => "9/16/2013",
                            "65" => "9/16/2013",
                            "66" => "3/24/2014",
                            "67" => "5/27/2014",
                            "68" => null,
                            "69" => null,
                            "70" => "lorem ipsum2789",
                            "71" => null,
                            "72" => null,
                            "73" => null,
                            "74" => null,
                            "75" => null,
                            "76" => null,
                            "77" => "lorem ipsum2199",
                            "78" => "12,000.00",
                            "79" => "40,206.85",
                            "80" => "6,345.21",
                            "81" => "5,210.95",
                            "82" => null,
                            "83" => "63,763.01",
                            "84" => 'lorem ipsum2124',
                            "85" => "10,934.25",
                            "86" => null,
                            "87" => null,
                            "88" => null,
                            "89" => null,
                            "90" => "10,934.25"
                        ),

                    "id_lettre" => array
                        (
                            "2" => 30744
                        )

                )

);

$data_sent2 = array();
foreach($data_sent as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k=> $v) {
        $data_sent2[$value][$k] = array_values($v);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_sent2);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is being as expected, that is (this is just an excerpt):

```
<pre>Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_paragraphe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 9
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 7
                    [5] => 10
                    [6] => 3
                    [7] => 8
                    [8] => 11
                )

            [texte_tableau_paragraphe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => colonne1 ligne1 hhhhh
                    [1] => colonne2 ligne1 22222222222
                    [2] => colonne3 ligne1 333333333333
                    [3] => colonne1 ligne2 444444444
                    [4] => colonne2 ligne2 5555555555555
                    [5] => colonne3 ligne2 6666666666666
                    [6] => colonne1 ligne3 777777777sdfgvsd
                    [7] => colonne2 ligne3 88888888888
                    [8] => colonne3 ligne3 9999999999999
                )

            [id_lettre] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30744
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_paragraphe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                    [1] => 17
```

But in the context of my project, where the array is being received by Ajax in the form of of $_POST ($_POST is as same as $data_sent - I took $_POST data to run a test outside of my project), when doing this:

```
$sentElements = array();
if (is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k=> $v) {
            $sentElements[$key][$k] = array_values($v);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sentElements);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

I'm getting exactly the initial array. Which means array_values() doesn't work as expected.

Any ideas?

What I really want is to have indexes starting from 0, not from 91. Therefore, I want to replace 91 through 99 by 0 through 99 in the array id_paragraphe for instance.

Comment: `$sentElements[$key]` code looks to do that explicitly - are you forgetting to array_values the variable arrayData/sentElements? It's not clear what you mean when you say it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean $sentElements[$key] will output exactly what I want, which is indexes 91 through 99 replaced with 0 through 8?

Comment: *"Which means array_values() doesn't work as expected."* -- No, it doesn't mean `array_values()` doesn't work as expected. There are many reasons why your code does not produce the expected output. The most probable one is that the input you feed to it does not look as you think it looks like. Run a sample with a small input data set, add `var_dump($arrayData)` and `var_dump($sentElements)` to your code and update the question with the output produced by them.

Comment: ... another possible cause is the incorrect use of [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Posting the output of `var_dump()` as HTML does not help anybody. If you need an answer to the question you have to put some effort into making it easy to read.

Comment: _"The most probable one is that the input you feed to it does not look as you think it looks like."_ print_r() is telling me that I have an array, what might be the true nature of the code I'm passing to array_value()? Since I'm using JavaScript and rendering everything in my console I couldn't get output from var_dump() in other form. Could you tell me what kind of new information you will get from var_dump() rather tha print_r() since we know the type of every content?

Comment: If I copy those var_dump outputs your question contained before you edited them out again into a jsfiddle, the result is this, https://jsfiddle.net/kn0vocy8/ - notice how the keys `id_paragraphe`, `texte_tableau_paragraphe` etc. have turned into numeric indexes now? So by the looks of it, you are simply applying array_values one level to early here.

Comment: @04FS I see what you mean, this means that I'm getting some different result now, which also means array_value() is working but I didn't use it in the way i should have used it to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the remark of @04FS, I've been able to transform the range of numeric indexes in "id_paragraphe", "texte_tableau_paragraphe" and "id_lettre" arrays, which is what I needed to achieve. I wanted the indexes to start from 0, not from 91. Below is the correction I've made:

```
$sentElements= array();
if (is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k=> $v) {
            foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                $sentElements[$key][$k][$k2] = array_values($v2);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sentElements);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

The result is:

```
[sent_elements] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_paragraphe] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 4
                            [2] => 9
                            [3] => 2
                            [4] => 7
                            [5] => 10
                            [6] => 3
                            [7] => 8
                            [8] => 11
                        )

                    [texte_tableau_paragraphe] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => colonne1 ligne1  hhhhh
                            [1] => colonne2   ligne1  22222222222
                            [2] => colonne3 ligne1 333333333333
                            [3] => colonne1 ligne2  444444444
                            [4] => colonne2 ligne2 5555555555555
                            [5] => colonne3 ligne2  6666666666666
                            [6] => colonne1 ligne3 777777777fsdfsfd
                            [7] => colonne2 ligne3 88888888888
                            [8] => colonne3 ligne3 9999999999999
                        )

                    [id_lettre] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 30744
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id_paragraphe] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 16
                            [1] => 17
                            [2] => 18
                            [3] => 19
                            [4] => 20
                            [5] => 21
                            [6] => 22
                            [7] => 23
                            [8] => 24
                            [9] => 25
                            [10] => 26
etc.
```